# Ruby on Rails Form for Calculating Dice Rolls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating a web application as a training project that will take three inputs (Integer values for number of dice, number of sides and number of rolls) and input that into a series of tables that will facilitate calculations and the output of the results, and the saving of historical data (past rolls.)

I'm stuck.

Here is my ERB for the form:

```
<%= form_for(@run) do |f| %>
      How many dice: <%= f.number_field :die_count, :placeholder => "# of dice" %><br>
      How many sides: <%= f.number_field :die_sides, :placeholder => "# of sides" %><br>
      How many rolls: <%= f.number_field :rolls, :placeholder => "# of rolls" %><br>
      <%= f.submit "Roll!" %>
  <% end %>
```

Here's my Model:

```
  class Run < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rolls
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :die_count, :rolls, :die_sides

  validates_numericality_of :die_count, :die_sides, :rolls

end
```

Here's my pertinent Controller info:

```
  def new
    @run = Run.new
  end

  def create
    @run = Run.new(run_params)
  end

  private

  def run_params
    params.require(:run).permit(:die_count, :die_sides, :rolls)
  end
```

For good measure, here's the migrate for making my DB table:

```
  class CreateRuns < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :runs do |t|
      t.integer :die_count
      t.integer :die_sides
      t.integer :roll_count
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

At this point, I just want it to create a new record in the Run model. Here's the error I'm getting with the input of 5, 5, and 5 into the number_fields and click my submit button:

[image: The Roadblock]

If I am reading this correctly, my application wants to iterate through the individual numbers as if they were arrays, but it can't because they are strings. This confuses me because they aren't strings in the first place. They are integers.

Pulling my hair out on this one.

Comment: Is there a method in your controller that is supposed to display the results of your calculation?

Comment: Not yet. I originally was going to just redirect to the /runs/new view and add rows to the database. Would a #show method be required?

Comment: Post your _Runs Controller_ please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:rolls` is a reference to another model called `Roll` (have you created it?).
`:roll_count` is the attribute of your `Run` model that defines the number of rolls (as visible in your migration table).

They are two very different things, even though it stands to reason that `:roll_count` should in theory be equal to the number of `Roll` records your `Run` record 'owns'.

In your form, replace `:rolls` by `:roll_count`. Do the same in the `run_params` method in your controller. And also in the two validations in your model. (checklist: that's **4** places where you need to modify that symbol name).

In your controller, also change the content of your `create` method to `@run = Run.create(run_params)`.

Edited (clarity): `Run.new(params)` creates a new instance of a `Run` object but doesn't save it in your DB. `Run.create(params)` creates the object AND saves it.

Finally, in your model, comment out the `has_many :rolls` until you have actually implemented the `Roll` model (no pun intended!) ; do the same for `belongs_to :user` if the `User` model is not implemented either.

After these changes, your form should normally work and data should be saved in your `runs` database table.

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you so much! Marking this one as solution because of depth of response. I've confirmed data is saving correctly. Now on to figure out how to get the roll_number of the rolls table to increment and get the results table to populate the random numbers. Thanks for helping clear the log jam!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you meant to replace `rolls` with `roll_count` everywhere in your code.

`How many rolls: <%= f.number_field :roll_count, :placeholder => "# of rolls" %><br>`

and

`validates_presence_of :die_count, :roll_count, :die_sides
validates_numericality_of :die_count, :die_sides, :roll_count`

and

`def run_params
    params.require(:run).permit(:die_count, :die_sides, :roll_count)
end`

Comment: It's always the little stuff!!